# $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a torsion $\mathbb{Z}$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading through some chapters of Dummit and Foote Abstract Algebra book and in one of the examples from Projective Modules section they state that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a torsion $\mathbb{Z}$-module. So if I understand the quotient modules correctly, to show that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a torsion $\mathbb{Z}$-module we need to show that for every element $a$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ there exists some non-zero element $r$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $ra \in \mathbb{Z}$. But we know that every $a$ can be written as $x/y$, where $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ thus we can always take $r=y$ and we can then conclude that indeed every $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a torsion $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Great, thanks @Max

Comment: Your argument is correct.